# Bootstrap switch with own text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I’d like to be able to add a LOCK / UNLOCK behaviour on the checkbox using twitter bootstrap. I found a similar sample at  [boostrap-switch.org](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org) at the section of Label Text. In this example they have used ON-TV-OFF, Similarly I want to give my own text in the place of ON, OFF. Like UNLOCK-Username-LOCK.

LOCK should be disappeared by clicking on UNLOCK then output should be like XXX-LOCK

UNLOCK should be disappeared by click on ON text then output should be like UNLOCK-XXX

How can I do this with bootstrap?

Comment: Edit the HTML/CSS/JS. It's an open source project.

Comment: @Ranveer, please let me know if you know the specific code edit, on which part i have to edit?

Answer (score 0):

It's a Github repository. Go to /build/js and in the bootstrap-switch.js change the string  in the following:

```
html = "ON";
```

It's the line 35 of the js file.

Similarly change the string in:

```
html = "OFF";
```

i.e. line 47.

Answer (score -1):

This might not be exact same thing as [boostrap-switch.org](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/), but I have done it using `fadeTo()` property of jquery.

Here is the jsfiddle output [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nVaX9/3/).